# Fork and init startup

Tags: linux, daemon, init

I was reading some papers regarding how forking work in linux and why is it needed to call fork to create daemon  and why the parent should exit so the init can take control of newly created process and send it to background
But this all is in case of if i start daemon from terminal manually so TTY is attached .

How about when i add it to startup and by default init start the daemon and controls it so no TTY is attached 
In that case i am little confused as how it is handled
Little light on this would be helpful 
Regards

Comment: ...and just to throw a wrench into your question, note that most modern init alternatives like "upstart" and "systemd" more commonly expect your program to stay in the foreground, so the whole concept of the "fork and exit" daemon is sort of going away.

Comment: Got better then . So how daemon is supposed to be started in foreground when there is no foreground  ?

Comment: @Amir: Bad choice of words by larsks. "stay in the foreground" just means "do not fork&exit".

Comment: Will you please link some documents about this behaviour and descriptions ?